# Line-height property not working in media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a button and everything works perfect in all screen sizes except when I create a media query, `line-height` property stop working. I want to have my text in button centered just as it is on bigger screen sizes. But when I resize white text jumps to the bottom of the button. So, down below is a fiddle. :)

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/846p18tb/5/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `line-height` and add `padding` and `margin` to `zero`.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
 .main-group .btn.btn-green h3 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/846p18tb/7/)